# Parse retrieve pointer from current user in javascript

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform

In Parse I have the User table set up with a number of columns, most of which are Strings but one is a Pointer to another Parse Class. I want to use this pointer in a query

In Java I can access the pointer to use in my query as follows:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject comParent = currentUser.getParseObject("ComParent");
```

In JavaScript I have tried using:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var comParent = currentUser.get("ComParent");
```

But this returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the documentation:](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers)

"By default, when fetching an object, related Parse.Objects are not fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched like so:"

```
var post = fetchedComment.get("parent");
post.fetch({
  success: function(post) {
    var title = post.get("title");

  }
});
```

**So you should write:**

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var comParent = currentUser.get("ComParent");
comParent.fetch({
    success: function(comParent) {
        var name = comParent.get("Name");
        alert(name); // this one will work
    }
});
alert(comParent.get("Name")); // this one wont work, see below
```

Just remember that `success` is an asynchronous callback,as such `comParent` will not be available outside the `success` function as shown above, if you need to access `comParent` outside of `success` check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/27673839/1376624

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. My issue was a combination of 2 things. Firstly, I was not correctly fetching the object as you rightly point out. Secondly, I was trying to fetch an object from a user which did not have an associated ComParent object (Doh!). Anyway, your solution put me onto the need to fetch the object but I don't think it is the currentUser that should have the fetch, it is comParent:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var comParent = currentUser.get("ComParent");
    comParent.fetch({
        success: function(comParent) {
            var name = comParent.get("Name");
            alert(name);
        }
    });
```

Thanks again @DelightedD0D